# Variable Frequency Oscilator (MHz Range)

Tags: oscillator

For a small hobby project, I need something that is able to variably and smoothly oscillate between the range of 300MHz-500MHz depending on a potentiometer (or some other sort of variable input). The output would be SIN. Any suggestions or admonishments would be very much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Was wondering if it could be done in analogue, then found: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16512/is-this-a-suitable-sine-wave-osc-how-would-i-control-the-frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is a *voltage-controlled oscillator* or VCO. There are lots of vendors that sell them.

Many VCO's will have logic level (square wave) outputs --- you'll need to look for one specifically with a sine wave output.

Also, 300-500 MHz is nearly an octave tuning range. You may have to look through a lot of parts before you find one that can cover this range.

Alternately, if you're designing for a reasonable volume product or have a budget to back you up, most vendors of frequency control parts are very happy to do custom products. The main drawback is there's typically something like 16-24 week lead time to get one made custom.

If you are just doing a one-off, or can't afford the wait time, there are various ways to build your own from standard parts.

Comment: (editing out my bad comment)

Comment: I was trying to give a "good shopping question" answer to a "bad shopping question."

Comment: Fixed it up. :)